# How to replace id in array with the names related to that id from another array in angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays with some data like below.

```
client = [{id: 1, name: client 1}, {id: 2, name: client 2}];

company = [{id: 1, name: company 1}, {id: 2, name: company 2}];

case = [{id: 1, client: 1, company: 2, name: case 1}, 
        {id: 2, client: 1, company: 1, name: case 2}];
```

in my view I need to show it like

- client: client 1  company: company 2  case: case 1
- client: client 1  company: company 1  case: case 2

How can I achieve that? My basic requirement is need to replace the case array id with related array's names. I'm new to angular and I'm using angular 4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you should remove the angular tag, this has little to do with angular. This should get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your joining table is `case`, iterate over it and create a new array out of it with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) :

```js
const clients = [{id: 1, name: 'client 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'client 2'}];
const companies = [{id: 1, name: 'company 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'company 2'}];
const cases = [{id: 1, client: 1, company: 2, name: 'case 1'}, {id: 2, client: 1, company: 1, name: 'case 2'}];

const joined = cases.reduce((p ,n) => {
  p.push({
    client: clients.find(c => c.id === n.client).name,
    company: companies.find(c => c.id === n.company).name,
    case: n.name
  });
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(joined);
```

**EDIT** For the sake of it, you can even reduce the code with a spread :

```js
const clients = [{id: 1, name: 'client 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'client 2'}];
const companies = [{id: 1, name: 'company 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'company 2'}];
const cases = [{id: 1, client: 1, company: 2, name: 'case 1'}, {id: 2, client: 1, company: 1, name: 'case 2'}];

const joined = cases.reduce((p ,n) => [...p, {
  client: clients.find(c => c.id === n.client).name,
  company: companies.find(c => c.id === n.company).name,
  case: n.name
}], []);

console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 1):

use forech to along with find to create a new array.

```
   clients = [{id: 1, name: 'client 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'client 2'}];
  companies = [{id: 1, name: 'company 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'company 2'}];

  case: any[] = [{id: 1, client: 1, company: 2, name: 'case 1'}, 
        {id: 2, client: 1, company: 1, name:'case 2'}];
  custom = [];

  constructor(){
    this.case.forEach((item) => {
      let company =  this.companies.find((c) => c.id === item.company)
      let client =  this.clients.find((c) => c.id === item.client)
      this.custom.push({
        id : item.id,
        company: (company) ? company.name : null,
        client: (client) ? client.name : null,
        name: item.name
      })
    })
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkpguf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thanks for the reply. But this is not what I want I have three separate arrays and those are links with id's. In view I need to show the names not the Id's